# which is the use of position and name in putextra?

Tags: android

How do I use `.get[position]` and `name` in `.putextra` in Android, and how can I use `position` in `putextra` using an array?

```
ainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.koala_copy, R.drawable.lighthouse_copy};

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                            long id) {
        Intent b = new Intent(SimpleListViewActivity.this, Nextclass.class);
        b.putExtra("Name", myImageList.get[position]);
        b.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        finish();
        startActivity(b);
    }

    private ArrayAdapter<String> getListAdapter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null; 
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is very unclear what you mean. and your code as well. Firstly what are you trying to put in the intent? It looks like you're trying to get a position in an array. .get is not a valid array method. an arraylist yes, but not array. Even so, you wouldn't just put a blank variable.

What i suspect that you want the position of a listview selected put into an intent and then fire off to the next activity.

```
b.putExtra("Name", pos);
```

is all you need for that, believe it or not, since the int pos (position) conveniently comes as a parameter on the onclicklistener. Perhaps on the next activity you want to display 1 of the two images in an imageview. There you can use a simple if statement, or case if you plan to put more, to choose what image to show. As of now i can see no business of that int array there being where it is.

---

**EDIT:**
There is no magic in the implementation of displaying the image in the next activity. As one would intuit, you get the int that you just put in the intent. Then depending on what the number is, you perform an imageview drawable assignment on a new drawable.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int listPos = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Name");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        switch (listPos) {
        case 0: image.setImageResource(R.drawable.koala_copy);
        break;
        case 1: image.setImageResource(R.drawable.lighthouse_copy);
        break;
        }
    }
```

as for getting the image from an sd card, perhaps this web page will help:
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/load-bitmap-file-from-sd-card.html

it has a sample file you can download, too.

Finally, in order to not just give you fish for the day, but help you fish - may i suggest some video tutorials? This is a great resource in addition to stackoverflow for acquiring knowledge about android development: http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6

Comment: sorry,, but i am trying to display image in new activity when click on listview control.... how i do it... please help...... i create array of two images which is located in the drawable directory... i mean want to display the image of drawable directory in new activity... and also try using display image which is located in sdcard... thanks...

Comment: there's no need for an array, at least yet. Moreover, wouldn't it be better to load numbers or strings into an array and show images based on that? Any time you get away with putting simpler data in memory instead of complex objects, you should.